# How to view current Resource Governor Classification Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, resource-governor

Is there a way to view what is the current/active Classification Function that the Resource Governor is currently using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classifier function is stored in the `sys.resource_governor_configuration` table:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(classifier_function_id) AS [ClassifierFunctionName]
from sys.resource_governor_configuration;
```